# how to get index of current element in a parent element in WPF

Tags: wpf

I am developing an application in WPF and kinda new to WPF. I have been struggling to find the solution but failed. So posting here. Please guide me.

A stack panel has five text box. I want to know when ever user types in a text box, the index of the text box in the stack panel.

```
private void OnKeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)        {//required code??}
```

What I mean is, is he/she typing in the first textbox or second box or third text box or fourth text box or fifth text box? How can I get this in C# script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void UIElement_OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox textBox = (TextBox) sender;
            StackPanel parent = (StackPanel)textBox.Parent;

            int index = parent.Children.IndexOf(textBox);
        }
```